# ExtJS grid dynamic combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

i have this case:
i have product which have many warehouse, and a warehouse have many units

i have warehouse combobox and units combobox, when i change the value of warehouse combobox, the values in Units combobox changed (the same record).

here i make some sencha fiddle about it:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1o08

when i edit a warehouse combobox the listener read all the record on the grid & change another combobox value in different record.

what i want is when i change warehouse in record 1 then only units combobox in record 1 that changed.
i'm using ExtJS 5.0.1.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `itemupdate` listener is calling `widget.setStoreManually` for all the comoboxes. We have to call it only for the corresponding combobox. We will only it when the recordId of the widget & the updated records matches.

Your `itemupdate` listener will look like:

```
itemupdate: function(rec,idx) {
            if(widget.getWidgetRecord().id==rec.id) // only when both id matches
               widget.setStoreManually(widget, rec)
}
```